# No Desktop - 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, ati, desktop-environments

Before I start. I am kind of new to Ubuntu.

I upgrade to 13.04 and it seemed to go well. But when I logged in I got no launcher or anything. I can right click to bring up a menu and use the shortcut for the terminal. and run programs from the terminal.

I have tried the methods to fix a broken compiz. i have tried to install radeon drives as I am using an old Radeon 9200. but afterwards when I try the fglrxinfo command, I get "Illegal instruction". I have tried a couple of other things but with no lucky.

Does anyone have any ideas?

edit: forgot to say, I can login as guest but the desktop is very very slow

Comment: my friend had this problem too but im not shure if it will work for you, all he did was reinstall ubuntu and everything worked.

Comment: hmmm, try restarting lightdm. press `ctrl`+`alt`+`f2`, log in, and enter `sudo service lightdm restart`. Not quite sure why, but I remember it solved similar problems for me when I first installed Ubuntu.

Comment: btw, the shortcut to bringing up the terminal is `ctrl`+`alt`+`T`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. what I have done just now is install gnome desktop. it seems to be working at the moment. nothing special. fingers crossed I can get ubuntu desktop working at some point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)